# Coming from Firebase 8.9.1, are there any big differences with the new version of Firebase v9?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm planning to build a web app in such a short time. I'm planning to just use what I've learned in Firebase 8.9.1. However, I've learned that there was a new version of Firebase. These are the functions that I would most probably be using:

- Database: Firestore
- Will be using Firebase Authentication
- The usual CRUD operations
- Queries and distributed counters for functions similar to inventories
- Firebase Hosting

Are there any big differences between the two versions? And is it alright if I'll just stay with version 8.9.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is mostly the syntax but all services work as they used to. I would recommend updating to newer version so you get all the new features from Firebase.

Comment: I'll be using it together with Reactjs. There's not much difference, right?

Comment: The API is completely different, but functionally they're the same. To learn how to upgrade, see this [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) and check the code samples in the documentation.